# How do I set Fredhopper "Universe?"

Tags: service

I'm following the Fredhopper Access Server (FAS) installation guide and want to start [the services](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2010_SP1/task_C9568F68652147BC836E550304E8E0E9).

I tried the following:

`C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\bin>startloader`

I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
No universes given, and autodetection failed.
Please run this script from the base directory of your FAS installation!
Usage: startloader [-I instance] [universe...]
```

I'm not sure which is the `base directory`--I got similar errors starting from these.

- C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\
- C:\fredhopper\instance01\
- C:\fredhopper\

`java -version` shows:

```
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

It looks like I'm missing a path in a configuration file. Where can I find more information on how to set the `universe?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run bin\Startloader, not startloader.

In other words, go to the C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\ folder then run bin\startloader

Comment: Ok, I had two things going on. I eventually figured out the path (bin), so +1 for this answer. That error was originally `'startloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` With that fixed, I realized I had the wrong `%path%` set in system variables, it needs to point to the JDK installation (duh).